# logistic regression classifier for prediction in Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, kaggle

I am trying to make a script that takes a json file(pizza-train.json) (from [this Kaggle competition](https://www.kaggle.com/c/random-acts-of-pizza/). I want to extract the request_text field from each dictionary in the list, and construct a bag of words representation of the string (string to count-list).

The next step is to train a logistic regression classifier to predict the variable “requester_received_pizza”. I want to train the 90% of the data and predict the 10%. The problem is that I don't know how to predict the 10%. Any advice would be really helpfull!

```
import json
from sklearn.cross_validation import train_test_split
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer


f_json = json.load(open('pizza-train.json'))
request_text = []
y = []

for item in f_json[:100]:
    request_text.append(item['request_text'])
    y.append(item['requester_received_pizza'])

vectorizer = CountVectorizer(min_df=1, lowercase=True, stop_words='english')

train_data_features = vectorizer.fit_transform(request_text)
train_data_features = train_data_features.toarray()


print 'Shape = '
print train_data_features.shape
vocab = vectorizer.get_feature_names()
print '\n'
print 'Vocab = '
print vocab


x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(train_data_features, y, test_size=0.10)
```

Comment: Have you tried `sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression`?

Comment: First you create a model using the training data.  Then take the test data set, feed the inputs into your model, and compare the output to the known value from the test data.  Calculate the SSE and use it to compare different models.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might do it like this:

```
alg = sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression()
alg.fit(x_train, y_train)
test_score = alg.score(x_test, y_test)
```

You should read the sklearn docs [logistic regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html) and [cross validation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/cross_validation.html), which are very good and provide more sophisticated methods for validating your models. [This](https://www.dataquest.io/course/kaggle-competitions) tutorial for the Kaggle Titanic competition might also be useful.